# Ошибка в retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Доброго времени суток. 
При попытке retrofit2.3.0 загрузить с сервера xml возникает следующая ошибка `Could not locate ResponseBody converter for java.util.List<com.example.testapplication.data.network.model.ShopResult>.`
Хотя в коде четко добавляется конвертер для xml.

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl(ServerAPI.HOST)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createAsync())
            .validateEagerly(true)
            .build();
```

В gradle я добавил `compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.3.0'){
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }
   compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0"`

Подскажите в чем причина ошибки и как ее устранить?

Comment: Покажите код самого вызова.

Comment: А также код вашей модели `ShopResult` и xml, который приходить с сервера

Comment: нужен ваш модельный класс и сам запрос. ошибка скорее всего там. дополните вопрос

Comment: Вопрос закрыт, я сам нашел причину.

Answer (score 0):

Причина ошибки была в том, что нужно было правильно прописывать аннотации и правильно перенести структуру xml в виде классов.